# Is there a way to split a Query?

Tags: php, split

Is there a way to dismantle a query? My query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT C18_NLE00102.DETAIL
,C18_NLE00102.LIB_STATUS
,CLIENT_NLE00103.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C
,DATEPART( week,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Week
,DATEPART( year,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Year
 FROM 
C18_NLE001 C18_NLE00102 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 CLIENT_NLE00103
 ON C18_NLE00102.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE00103.INDICE
```

I need a output like:

```
Array (
    [0] => SELECT C18_NLE00102.DETAIL 
    [1] => C18_NLE00102.LIB_STATUS 
    [2] => CLIENT_NLE00103.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C 
    [3] => DATEPART(week,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Week
    [4] => DATEPART( year,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Year  
    [5] => FROM C18_NLE001 C18_NLE00102 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 CLIENT_NLE00103 ON C18_NLE00102.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE00103.INDICE
)
```

My output is now:

```
Array (
    [0] => SELECT C18_NLE00102.DETAIL 
    [1] => C18_NLE00102.LIB_STATUS 
    [2] => CLIENT_NLE00103.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C 
    [3] => DATEPART( week 
    [4] => C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Week 
    [5] => DATEPART( year 
    [6] => C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Year FROM C18_NLE001 C18_NLE00102 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 CLIENT_NLE00103 ON C18_NLE00102.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE00103.INDICE 
)
```

I'm using:

```
$more_dwarf_array = split(', ?',$QuerySaved );
print_r($more_dwarf_array);
```

The problem is the DATEPART.

Comment: You will need something a bit more sophisticated than split for this. A search for "sql tokenizer php" or "sql lexer php" should give you a good start

Answer (score 1):

A working code for this sample:

```
$string = 'SELECT C18_NLE00102.DETAIL
,C18_NLE00102.LIB_STATUS
,CLIENT_NLE00103.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C
,DATEPART( week,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Week
 ,DATEPART( year,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Year
 FROM 
C18_NLE001 C18_NLE00102 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 CLIENT_NLE00103
 ON C18_NLE00102.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE00103.INDICE';

$array = preg_split('/(?<=^)\s*,|^(?=\s*FROM)/m', $string); // Split by ',' that's at the beginning of the line and also split if there is a FROM at the beginning
$array[count($array)-1] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $array[count($array)-1]); // This is to remove all newlines/tabs in the FROM part
$array = array_map('trim', $array); // Remove spaces/newlines from the values of the array
print_r($array); // output
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SELECT C18_NLE00102.DETAIL
    [1] => C18_NLE00102.LIB_STATUS
    [2] => CLIENT_NLE00103.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C
    [3] => DATEPART( week,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Week
    [4] => DATEPART( year,C18_NLE00102.DATE) as Year
    [5] => FROM C18_NLE001 C18_NLE00102 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 CLIENT_NLE00103 ON C18_NLE00102.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE00103.INDICE
)
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Gzc1C).